# Why check key in array is does not work in this code?

Tags: php, arrays

I try use this construction code:

```
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$samle_array=array('34','164','178','195');
if (isset($samle_array[$cat])) {
//
} else {
//
}
```

But it doesn't work.

It try use array_key_exists:

```
$cat=$_GET['cat'];
$samle_array=array('34','164','178','195');
if (array_key_exists($cat,$samle_array)) {
//
} else {
//
}
```

But it doesn't work too.

Comment: What keys are you using?34? 164? Those are the values not keys. Use in_array.

Comment: array_key_exists used to check the key in array not value. you have need to use in_array. if(in_array($cat, $samle_array)){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking a values against array you need to use `in_array` function.

> [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) : Checks if a value exists in an array

So in your case approach it as

```
$cat    =$_GET['cat'];
$samle_array = array('34','164','178','195');
if(in_array($cat, $samle_array)){
  // business logic
}
```